# How do I reverse the order of integration for this double integral?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_{\sin(x)}^2dydx$$ This is the integral in question. My closest was $$\int_0^{2}\int^{\sin^{-1}(y)}_2dxdy$$
but I believe this is wrong.
Sorry for the bad formatting, It's my first time using it properly

Comment: Draw a picture, and you'll see that you have to break the integral into two pieces.  When $0\leq y <1$, $x$ is limited by the sine wave, but when $1\leq y\leq2$, $x$ takes all values between $0$ and $\pi/2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As saulspatz pinted out in the comment, you will have to split the integral into two if you switch the order:
$$
\int_0^1\int_0^{\sin^{-1}(y)}dxdy+\int_{1}^2\int_0^{\pi/2}dxdy
$$

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Actually,
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_{\sin(x)}^2\,dy\,dx = \int_0^{\pi/2}\left(2-\sin(x)\right)\,dx = \pi-1$$

Comment: Sorry. Maybe I wasn't specific enough but I didn't mean to solve the integral, only to reverse the order of integration. Thank you, though!